# Get PTS from raw H264 mdat generated by iOS AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, avfoundation, h.264, avassetwriter

I'm trying to simultaneously read and write H.264 mov file written by AVAssetWriter. I managed to extract individual NAL units, pack them into ffmpeg's AVPackets and write them into another video format using ffmpeg. It works and the resulting file plays well except the playback speed is not right. How do I calculate the correct PTS/DTS values from raw H.264 data? Or maybe there exists some other way to get them?

Here's what I've tried:

1. Limit capture min/max frame rate to 30 and assume that the output file will be 30 fps. In fact its fps is always less than values that I set. And also, I think the fps is not constant from packet to packet.
2. Remember each written sample's presentation timestamp and assume that samples map one-to-one to NALUs and apply saved timestamp to output packet. This doesn't work.
3. Setting PTS to 0 or AV_NOPTS_VALUE. Doesn't work.

From googling about it I understand that raw H.264 data usually doesn't contain any timing info. It can sometimes have some timing info inside SEI, but the files that I use don't have it. On the other hand, there are some applications that do exactly what I'm trying to do, so I suppose it is possible somehow.

Comment: I'm also trying to simultaneously read H.264 from a mov file written by AVAssetWriter, and could not get to do it using pipes / regular file reading. How did you manage to read it while it's being written? Thanks!

Comment: Use regular file reading but instead of stopping on EOF reread again. Sooner or later your reading operation will succeed.

Comment: @kolyuchiy - dispatch sources make better use of the system. Set up a read source on the FILE descriptor. A block will be called when there is data to be read. If EOF occurs just clear the error on your FILE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will either have to generate them yourself, or access the Atom's containing timing information in the MP4/MOV container to generate PTS/DTS information. FFmpeg's mov.c in libavformat might help.

Each sample/frame you write with AVAssetWriter will map one to one with the VCL NALs. If all you are doing is converting then have FFmpeg do all the heavy lifting. It will properly maintain the timing information when going from one container format to another.

The bitstream generated by AVAssetWriter does not contain SEI data. It only contains SPS/PPS/I/P frames. The SPS also does not contain VUI or HRD parameters.

-- Edit --

Also, keep in mind that if you are saving PTS information from the CMSampleBufferRef's then the time base may be different from that of the target container. For instance AVFoundation time base is nanoseconds, and a FLV file is milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks! Actually CMSampleBuffers really do contain correct PTS that maps to output packets. I was just too lazy to go all the way in that direction. This solved my problem.